# Is there a real "Gmail Tap" app?

Tags: applications, sms, gmail

[Gmail Tap](http://gmailblog.blogspot.se/2012/03/introducing-gmail-tap.html), one of Google's April fools, would give the phone a three-keys Morse keyboard. Is there a way to get this functionality for real, preferably for input to any fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rgam.morsekeyboard

Answer (score 2):

There is another one: [Morse Code Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.emergent.android.morseime)

Comment: I couldn't get it to work: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88828/how-to-enable-morse-input