# How to easily change keyboard input application?

Tags: keyboard, sony-xperia-tipo

I have installed a [Morse code input method](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.emergent.android.morseime). I believe I have followed the instructions to enable it (it's enabled in settings).

However, I don't seem to be able to use it anywhere in any input field.
I have an Xperia Tipo cellphone with the Xperia Chinese keyboard which I use often, in addition to the inbuilt English keyboard.

Possibly, I'd also like to install a French keyboard and be able to easily switch between all these keyboards, but for the time being, I cannot even use the Morse keyboard although it's installed and enabled. How do I get started? Thanks.

Edit:

Ok, I found the setting "Default" keyboard, where I can choose between Xperia Chinese and Morse input and the other keyboards I previously installed. If I choose 'morse' then I can use it. The problem is now that I must chose between one or the other, and have to come back all the way to the settings to change keyboards. Is there any way to easily change between keyboard applications? I.e. whenever I need one specific keyboard application (Chinese, English, French or Morse) rapidly switch to the proper keyboard from within the application I am currently using (browser, messaging or whatever...) ?

Comment: Doesn't your phone have an item in the notification tray to switch keyboards?

Comment: @DanHulme It didn't have by default, but it does now that I have installed the app in the answer. Does it come by default in newer versions of android?

Comment: I can't tell you about "newer" versions of Android, because I don't know what version you're using.

Comment: @DanHulme That was indeed a silly question from me! ;) My phone is not rooted and runs Android 4.0.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. On your Keyboard, hold the settings icon

[image: Hold the gear]

2. Scroll Down and click "Change input method"

[image: Select "Change Input"]

3. A list will come up with all activated keyboards. Choose one and then your keyboard will change to the selected keyboard. All without the need for an external app.

[image: Select Input Method]

Answer (score 0):

Look for and install a "keyboard switcher" application.
I have installed this one: 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appaholics.keyboardswitch
and initial testing is encouraging.
I am simply surprised that this kind of functionality does not come by default...